# How can I compare complete groups in SQL without using pivot function in Redshift?

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift

I have a table, see schema below:

```
CREATE TEMP TABLE merchants
(
  merchant_id varchar(15)
  ,product_id varchar(15)
);

INSERT INTO merchants VALUES ('Merchant A','Product 1');
INSERT INTO merchants VALUES ('Merchant A','Product 2');
INSERT INTO merchants VALUES ('Merchant A','Product 3');
INSERT INTO merchants VALUES ('Merchant B','Product 1');
INSERT INTO merchants VALUES ('Merchant B','Product 2');
INSERT INTO merchants VALUES ('Merchant B','Product 3');
INSERT INTO merchants VALUES ('Merchant B','Product 4');
INSERT INTO merchants VALUES ('Merchant C','Product 1');
INSERT INTO merchants VALUES ('Merchant C','Product 2');
INSERT INTO merchants VALUES ('Merchant C','Product 3');
INSERT INTO merchants VALUES ('Merchant D','Product 5');

SELECT *
FROM merchants;
```

I need to find merchant pairings which sell the 1) same number of products AND 2) sell exactly same products.

The answer for above data would be :

Merchant A , Merchant C -- same row.

I came up with a really bad solution IMO, to find this, but I dont think it is scalable, since if products are more, I cannot hard code them as columns. Also my answer is in 2 rows, not as a pair.

```
CREATE TEMP TABLE merchants_profile AS 
(
SELECT 
  merchant_id
  , COUNT(DISTINCT product_id) AS num_products
  , SUM(CASE WHEN product_id = 'Product 1' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS num_1
  , SUM(CASE WHEN product_id = 'Product 2' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS num_2
  , SUM(CASE WHEN product_id = 'Product 3' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS num_3
  , SUM(CASE WHEN product_id = 'Product 4' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS num_4
  , SUM(CASE WHEN product_id = 'Product 5' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS num_5
FROM merchants
GROUP BY 1
);

SELECT A.merchant_id
FROM merchants_profile AS A 
INNER JOIN 
merchants_profile AS B 
ON A.merchant_id <> B.merchant_id
AND (A.num_products = B.num_products 
    AND A.num_1 = B.num_1 
    AND A.num_2= B.num_2 
    AND A.num_3 = B.num_3
    AND A.num_4 = B.num_4
    AND A.num_5 = B.num_5)
```

Answer:

merchant_id
Merchant C
Merchant A

Can anyone think of a more creative/efficient way to do this, without using pivot functionality. I need to solve this in redshift.

As can be seen, my solution isn't correct, and I cannot think of a way to find pairs.

Answer (score 1):

Does this meet your need?

```
select distinct
       listagg(product_id,',') within group (order by product_id) as product_combos, 
       listagg(merchant_id,',') within group (order by merchant_id) over (partition by product_combos) as merchant_list,
       count(1) over (partition by product_combos) as count_of_merchants
from merchants
group by merchant_id
order by count_of_merchants desc;
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to use `listagg()`.  These produces lists of merchants for each set of products:

```
select products, listagg(merchant_id) within group (order by merchant_id) as merchants
from (select merchant_id,
             listagg(product_id) within group (order by product_id) as products
      from merchants_profile
      group by merchant_id
     ) m
group by products
having count(*) > 1;
```

You can do the same thing without aggregating at the merchant level, but this is simpler.